# Encounter RequestBroker--ParseUri

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I request this API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{uid}/mailFolders/{mid}/messages/delta
```

encountered this specific error

```
HttpCode: 400 

err_code: RequestBroker--ParseUri
err_message: Could not find a property named 'ChangeKdy' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.
request_id: 3f4a92df-3085-4c8c-a7bb-48b6fd6343ac
date: 2019-07-30T02:35:06
```

But it seems to be fixed at this related issue:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1888

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1888) issue, this was a temporary issue with the Microsoft Graph that has since been resolved.